# What's the probability of drawing every card at least from 82 cards, with replacement?

Tags: probability

What is the probability that if I draw 82 cards at random with replacemnt from a standard deck, every card is drawn at least once?

I've been banging my head against a wall for hours now, any help please.

I tried a smaller scale problem, so if I draw 52 cards, then it would be 1/52*1/52*1/52....52 times, so (1/52)^52. I think...

Comment: No, $(1/52)^{52}$ is the probability of drawing a specified card, say the jack of diamonds, $52$ times. If you draw $52$ cards with replacement from a $52$-card deck, the probability of drawing every card once is $52!/52^{52}$, which is still pretty small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: You use Stirling numbers of the Second Kind. So the answer ends up being 52!*S(82,52). Refer to this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy problem.  See:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: Thank you for the response, Im gonna look at it right now...